# How to update/rebuild generated JavaScript files in a Cordova Android app?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

When I make a change in one of my application's JavaScript files and rebuild, the JavaScript file that is compiled in the platforms/android/scripts folder should also reflect those changes, should it not? However, this does not seem to be the case right now. The generated js file in the android directory is always the same. If I blank out the whole file, it rebuilds itself just as it was. How can I get it to rebuild WITH the changes I made in the original JS file?

Comment: how are you building? Are you using Cordova CLI or any other tool?

Comment: Cordova CLI -> cordova build android

Comment: I does it all time and it works. Why don't you remove android platform and add again